# How to configure avahi/nss_mdns to append .domain when using short names

Tags: linux, dns, avahi, mdns

I have environment with 2 or more servers (Ubuntu 18.04) each running *avahi-daemon*.

Avahi configuration file looks like:

```
[server]
host-name=n11
domain-name=alocal
browse-domains=alocal
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=no
deny-interfaces=docker0,lo
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=yes

[publish]
publish-hinfo=no
publish-workstation=yes


[reflector]

[rlimits]
```

The only difference in the avahi configuration between the servers is `host-name`: `host-name=n11`, or `n12`, `n13`, etc. respectively.

Here is my `/etc/mdns.allow` file:

```
.alocal
.alocal.
```

And the `hosts:` path of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:          files mdns4 [SUCCESS=return] mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

Everything works as expected: I can reach the servers using their full names: `n11.alocal`, `n12.alocal` etc.
The problem is that I can't use *short* names like `n11`, `n12`.

The question is: how to configure *avahi* and *nss_mdns* to automatically append `.alocal` when resolving domain names.